# Regex Matching Failure on NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, escaping, nspredicate

I execute a fetch with this `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *sameNameAndNumber = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name LIKE %@ AND number LIKE %@", field1, field2];
```

I get an exception:

2014-03-01 01:02:03.214 Memories[44692:3d03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN (string べきだ [べきだ], pattern まみれ (塗れ） [まにれ], case 0, canon 0)'

It looks like it's caused specifically by the string "まみれ (塗れ） [まにれ]".  Regardless of the other string it's being compared to, I get the above exception.

If I replace `LIKE` in the above code with `==`, I don't have this problem.  Is the use of `LIKE` causing it to treat my test as regex?  Does it not escape the parentheses and brackets in my string?  How would I have it ignore the parentheses and brackets in my queries?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name Contains %@ AND number Contains %@", field1, field2]` namely, use `"Contains"` to replace `"Like"` in `Predicate`.

If you use `"Like"` in a `Predicate` sentence, in case your `field1` is equal to **"（"** - A Chinese left bracket, your app crashes. Then use `"CONTAINS"` to replace `"LIKE"`.